# How to back up Heroku pg database from app itself?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

From a remote shell, using the Heroku toolbelt, it's pretty easy to trigger a db backup with:

`heroku pg:backups:capture --app my-app`

But how can I do that from a script running on the app itself? Something triggered from the heroku scheduler or manually like:

`heroku run node myScript.js --app my-app`

I have psql available so maybe that's an option although I don't know where to write to.
I don't see a way to do this via API here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference